# Travis CI timeout when generating code coverage for PHP

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage, travis-ci

I'm trying to get Travis CI to output a coverage report to be used with scrutinizer later. But I'm having trouble to get it to work.

When I add --coverage-clover=coverage.clover to my phpunit command, the generation of the coverage report fails with the following error:

`Generating code coverage report in Clover XML format ...PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.5.7/share/pyrus/.pear/php/PHP/Token.php on line 432`

This puzzles me for several reasons:

- generating the report takes only about 3 seconds on my local machine which actually seems to be slower than the test server (judging from the time the test suite needs)
- command line PHP does not have a timeout usually, so this seems to be setup deliberately on Travis-CI?
- it seems noone else is having this kind of problem as I couldn't find any similar reports when googling
- my bootstrap.php file for phpunit explicitly calls `set_time_limit(0);`

Is there a way to fix this on my side?

Full build log at https://travis-ci.org/splitbrain/dokuwiki/jobs/16522833

Comment: I just want to drop this github issue URL as a reference to those coming to this issue, who have not found more info yet: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1837